# How to dynamically create an object without changing the hierarchy by filtering and modifying other object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, javascript-objects

To create nested object we can do like below

```
function assign(obj, keyPath, value) {
   lastKeyIndex = keyPath.length-1;
   for (var i = 0; i < lastKeyIndex; ++ i) {
     key = keyPath[i];
     if (!(key in obj))
       obj[key] = {}
     obj = obj[key];
   }
   obj[keyPath[lastKeyIndex]] = value;
}

Usage:

var settings = {};
assign(settings, ['Modules', 'Video', 'Plugin'], 'JWPlayer');
```

which will result in this

```
"{"Modules":{"Video":{"Plugin":"JWPlayer"}}}"
```

I wanted to create nested Object which will have multiple children also in the same level.

I have the following data

```
{
    "children": [{
        "children": [{
            "children": [],
            "label": "A",
            "OrganizationId": 152,
            "id": 152
        }, {
            "children": [{
                "children": [{
                    "children": [],
                    "label": "B",
                    "OrganizationId": 180,
                    "id": 180
                }, {
                    "children": [],
                    "label": "C",
                    "OrganizationId": 181,
                    "id": 181
                }],
                "label": "D",
                "OrganizationId": 166,
                "id": 166
            }],
            "label": "E",
            "OrganizationId": 154,
            "id": 154

        }, {
            "children": [],
            "label": "F",
            "OrganizationId": 157,
            "id": 157
        }, {
            "children": [{
                "children": [{
                    "children": [],
                    "label": "G ",
                    "OrganizationId": 182,
                    "id": 182
                }],
                "label": "H",
                "OrganizationId": 167,
                "id": 167
            }],
            "label": "I",
            "OrganizationId": 155,
            "id": 155

        }]
    }]
}
```

So i have to modify the above object

**i.e pick only the label value and assign it as key in the new object 
 by maintaining the same hierarchy( expected output - below )**

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "A": "",
    "E": {
        "D": {
            "B": "",
            "C": ""
        }
    },
    "F": "",
    "I": {
        "H": {
            "G": ""
        }
    }
}
```

it would be of great help if someone can provide a hint or solution for implementing this. It would be really appreciated!

Please before giving negative votes, tell me what needs to be edited or what's wrong with this question.

Thanks!

Comment: @CertainPerformance hey, I've modified the question and added expected output.

Comment: Thanks. Oh, that's an interesting transformation!

Comment: @CertainPerformance is it not efficient or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code to handle it:

```js
function getNestedLabels(objectToProcess) {
  var obj = {};

  if (Array.isArray(objectToProcess.children) && objectToProcess.children.length > 0) {
    return objectToProcess.children.reduce(function(o, child) {
      o[child.label] = getNestedLabels(child);
      return o;
    }, obj)
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

---

```js
function getNestedLabels(objectToProcess) {
  var obj = {};

  if (Array.isArray(objectToProcess.children) && objectToProcess.children.length > 0) {
    return objectToProcess.children.reduce(function(o, child) {
      o[child.label] = getNestedLabels(child);
      return o;
    }, obj)
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

var d = {
  "children": [{
    "children": [{
      "children": [],
      "label": "A",
      "OrganizationId": 152,
      "id": 152
    }, {
      "children": [{
        "children": [{
          "children": [],
          "label": "B",
          "OrganizationId": 180,
          "id": 180
        }, {
          "children": [],
          "label": "C",
          "OrganizationId": 181,
          "id": 181
        }],
        "label": "D",
        "OrganizationId": 166,
        "id": 166
      }],
      "label": "E",
      "OrganizationId": 154,
      "id": 154

    }, {
      "children": [],
      "label": "F",
      "OrganizationId": 157,
      "id": 157
    }, {
      "children": [{
        "children": [{
          "children": [],
          "label": "G ",
          "OrganizationId": 182,
          "id": 182
        }],
        "label": "H",
        "OrganizationId": 167,
        "id": 167
      }],
      "label": "I",
      "OrganizationId": 155,
      "id": 155

    }]
  }]
};

console.log(getNestedLabels(d))
```

Comment: **Note:** I know first property is `"undefined"` but that is because first level object does not have a `label` property. So we should pass `d.children` instead of `d` but I have purposely passes `d` to signify this behavior.

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
function getNestedProperties(oldObj, newObj, property) {
  if (oldObj && typeof oldObj === "object") {
    let next = null;
    if (property in oldObj) {
      next = newObj[oldObj[property]] = {};
    }
    for (const key of Object.keys(oldObj)) {
      getNestedProperties(oldObj[key], next ? next : newObj, property);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const oldObject = {
  children: [
    {
      children: [
        {
          children: [],
          label: "A",
          OrganizationId: 152,
          id: 152
        },
        {
          children: [
            {
              children: [
                {
                  children: [],
                  label: "B",
                  OrganizationId: 180,
                  id: 180
                },
                {
                  children: [],
                  label: "C",
                  OrganizationId: 181,
                  id: 181
                }
              ],
              label: "D",
              OrganizationId: 166,
              id: 166
            }
          ],
          label: "E",
          OrganizationId: 154,
          id: 154
        },
        {
          children: [],
          label: "F",
          OrganizationId: 157,
          id: 157
        },
        {
          children: [
            {
              children: [
                {
                  children: [],
                  label: "G ",
                  OrganizationId: 182,
                  id: 182
                }
              ],
              label: "H",
              OrganizationId: 167,
              id: 167
            }
          ],
          label: "I",
          OrganizationId: 155,
          id: 155
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function getNestedProperties(oldObj, newObj, property) {
  if (oldObj && typeof oldObj === "object") {
    let next = null;
    if (property in oldObj) {
      next = newObj[oldObj[property]] = {};
    }
    for (const key of Object.keys(oldObj)) {
      getNestedProperties(oldObj[key], next ? next : newObj, property);
    }
  }
}

let newObject = {};
getNestedProperties(oldObject, newObject, "label");

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Few pointers. **1.** You are passing reference of object down the call stack. This can create a side-effect. **2.** `typeof === 'object'` will return true if I pass `null`. This will break the code. But in general, good idea to accept the key to process. +1

Comment: Thank you. I added additional check in my answer's `if` to fix the second one, but I'm not sure if it's possible to avoid the first one with my implementation?

Comment: You can check my implementation for that. Instead of passing reference down, try to pass it up. So you will always create a new object and return it. This way, this reference will not be saved with any function and minimize side effect